# You still pay costs for sending an agent to a space with the Kwisatz Haderach card in Dune: Imperium?

Tags: dune-imperium

A recent game had the table debating whether or no you still must pay costs of spaces your agent with the Kwisatz Haderach card. I could not find any place that specifically exempts the card's resent agent from having to pay.

The key thing that players suggested you don't is that **ANY** on the card is in all caps.

If you send your agent to a space requiring 2 spice, you still must pay the spice for that placement?

[image: Kwisatz Haderach card]

The card specific rules in the book:

> Kwisatz Haderach — You may play this card to take an Agent turn even if you have no Agents left in your supply, as it lets you send an Agent that is already on a board space. You may send an Agent back to the space that it was just on.
> If a board space can be used only once per game (High Council, Swordmaster), you can’t use Kwisatz Haderach to send an Agent there more than once. You can’t overcome The Voice and send an Agent to a board space where you can’t send an Agent.
> If you move an agent away from a space with a Maker icon, and that space remains empty until Phase 4, bonus spice does accumulate there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vital aspect of the rule clarification is in bold below:

> Kwisatz Haderach — You may play this card to take an **Agent turn** even
> if you have no Agents left in your supply, it lets you send an
> Agent that is already on board space.

This suggests that you still have the pay the costs just as you would during a normal Agent turn, described on Page 9 of [The Official Rulebook](https://www.direwolfdigital.com/dune-imperium/resources/rules/). Besides being able to move an occupied space (as described on the card), all other Agent turn rules apply.

Comment: That's a great find. I missed the "agent turn" bit. That makes all the difference.